# AS3 alpha of multiple objects adds up

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

It seems that when I set `alpha` on a `DisplayObjectContainer`, then it works on each individual child separately and not on the container as a whole. Consequently I start seeing overlap regions which are normally not visible.

[image]

My question is - How do I fade a container *as a whole*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `blendMode` property on your `DisplayObjectContainer` to `BlendMode.LAYER`